# How to provide user constant notification about Celery's Task execution status?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-views, celery

I integrated my project with celery in this way, inside `views.py` after receving request from the user

```
def upload(request):
    if "POST" == request.method:
        # save the file
        task_parse.delay()
        # continue
```

and in `tasks.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task
from uploadapp.main import aunit


@shared_task
def task_parse():
    aunit()
    return True
```

In short, the shared task will run a function `aunit()` from a third python file located in `uploadapp/` directory named `main.py`.
Let's assume that `aunit()` is a resource heavy process which takes time (like file parsing). As I integrated that with celery, It works totally asynchronously now which is good to me. So, the task start -> Celery process -> It finishes then celery set status to Finish. I can view that using `flower` .

But what I want to do is that I want to notify the user who is using my app also through django UI that `Your Task is done processing` as soon as Celery has finished processing at back-side and set status to SUCCESS.

Now, I know this is possible if :

1.) I constantly request the STATUS and see wheather it returns SUCCESS or not.

How do I do that via Celery. How can you query Celery Task status from your `views.py` and notify user asynchronously with just celery's python module ?

Comment: What about [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: `result = AsyncResult(task_id)`
`state = result.state`
you can return success state in views

Comment: @Roshan , That's an alternative but we need to constantly request that `state` from `views.py` or either from UI. How could we do that?

Comment: suggestion: Write a polling mechanism on following table
`django_celery_results.models.TaskResult `, used to store task results, and you can query this database table like any other Django model. @Marcus

Comment: I found this very helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935522/updating-client-that-a-celery-task-has-finished/33947913

Answer (score 0):

You need a real time mechanism. I would suggest Firebase. Update the Firebase real time DB field of user id with a boolean=True at the end of the celery task. Implement a javascript function to listen to Firebase database user_id object changes -> update the UI